django : CSRF verification failed. Request aborted. (tutorial2)
There is an error when logging in from the Django admin page.
I'm working on tutorial02, and I've tried various things and found related documents, so there's no change.
Please understand that the image is not uploaded, so it will be uploaded as a text message
=============================================================================
[cmd window]
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
May 24, 2024 - 14:14:40
Django version 5.0.4, using settings 'mysite.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.

[24/May/2024 14:14:46] "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[24/May/2024 14:14:46] "GET /admin/login/?next=/admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4158
Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.): /admin/login/
[24/May/2024 14:14:49] "POST /admin/login/?next=/admin/ HTTP/1.1" 403 2869

=============================================================================
[web browser]

Forbidden (403)

CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.

You are seeing this message because this site requires a CSRF cookie when submitting forms. This cookie is required for security reasons, to ensure that your browser is not being hijacked by third parties.

If you have configured your browser to disable cookies, please re-enable them, at least for this site, or for “same-origin” requests.
Help
Reason given for failure:
CSRF cookie not set.
In general, this can occur when there is a genuine Cross Site Request Forgery, or when Django’sCSRF mechanism has not been used correctly. For POST forms, you need toensure:
•Your browser is accepting cookies.
•The view function passes a request to the template’s rendermethod.
•In the template, there is a {% csrf_token%} template tag inside each POST form thattargets an internal URL.
•If you are not using CsrfViewMiddleware, then you must use csrf_protect on any views that use the csrf_tokentemplate tag, as well as those that accept the POST data.
•The form has a valid CSRF token. After logging in in another browsertab or hitting the back button after a login, you may need to reload thepage with the form, because the token is rotated after a login.
You’re seeing the help section of this page because you have DEBUG =True in your Django settings file. Change that to False,and only the initial error message will be displayed.
You can customize this page using the CSRF_FAILURE_VIEW setting.
I hope the admin login is successful.

Please add your HTML code which gives this error

http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/login/?next=/admin/

From your CMD window code, it looks like first time you hit admin panel with a GET request and it worked fine resulting in 200 response. then you used POST request for accessing the admin panel and it resulted in 403 response i.e. CSRF verification failed. May i ask why you are using a POST request to access the admin panel or is it just a mistake?

I didn't choose the POST method, I just followed the django tutorial of the site below.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/intro/tutorial02/

You probably need to use GET request instead of POST request to access the admin panel.

I didn't choose the POST method, I just followed the django tutorial of the site below. docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/intro/tutorial02
